# Why curl showing permission denied in tizen sdb?

Tags: tizen

I'm trying to send http request using curl from tizen sdb.

I made a request like "curl -v example.com"

An got error message:

```
bash-3.2# curl -v example.com
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x1e178d8; line 1398 (connection #-5000)
* Rebuilt URL to: example.com/
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 93.184.216.34...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 93.184.216.34: Permission denied
* Closing connection 0
* The cache now contains 0 members
* Expire cleared
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

I can request using browser app. So, there is no problem with device's internet connection. I was also able to send http request from tizen native app using libcurl library. But from sdb shell, curl request isn't working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to of my colleague, I finally found a solution. Turns out permission needed be added before running binary in tizen 3.0 . Following commands needed be run in sdb shell (in root mode)

```
# mount -o remount rw, /
# chsmack -e "System" /usr/bin/curl
```